# How to setup wifi adapter on linux mint?

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, usb

I am trying to setup my TP-Link Archer T4UH wireless Realtek 8812AU wifi usb adapter. I tried following the instructions on [this blog](http://sempike.blogspot.com/2015/09/linux-mint-ubuntu-compiling-ac1200.html). However, it still does not work. My network settings look like this:
[image: network settings]
You can see that I don't have the option of joining a wifi.
For reference, I am using Linux mint 20 and my lsusb output looks like this

```
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8009 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1532:011a Razer USA, Ltd BlackWidow Ultimate 2013
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 2357:0103 TP-Link Archer T4UH wireless Realtek 8812AU
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 045e:0779 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-3000
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1532:0043 Razer USA, Ltd DeathAdder Chroma
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**Edit:** Looking at the github it looks like I should be running

```
sudo modprobe -a rtl8812au
```

however, I get the following error

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rtl8812au': Device or resource busy
```

**Edit 2:** The driver manager detects the wifi adapter (see image below), however, even after enabling it I still cannot see wifi as an option in my network settings.

[image: driver manager]

Comment: *IF* you can get 'net access via ethernet or another wireless dongle, then you may want to take a look at [this](https://github.com/morrownr/8812au).

Comment: Amazing! Following that guide fixed it for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you KGIII. Following the instructions [here](https://github.com/morrownr/8812au) fixed the problem for me. For clarity, here the instructions rewritten here:
Installation Steps:

Step 1: Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)

Step 2: Update the system:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Step 3: Install the required packages (select the option for the OS you are using):

Option for Linux Mint (Ubuntu based) or Ubuntu (all flavors):

```
sudo apt-get install -y dkms git
```

Step 4: Create a directory to hold the downloaded driver:

Note: The technique used in this document is to create a directory in the home directory called src.

```
mkdir src
```

Step 5: Move to the newly created directory:

```
cd ~/src
```

Step 6: Download the driver:

```
git clone https://github.com/morrownr/8812au.git
```

Step 7: Move to the newly created driver directory:

```
cd ~/src/8812au
```

Step 8: Run the installation script:

```
sudo ./install-driver.sh
```

Step 10: Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Would you please incorporate the relevant commands from that link into your Answer? That way, if the link ever goes stale, this Answer will still be valuble. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will help.

I had trouble with an older PC when I installed Linuxmint 20 XFCE 64-bit on it, did a stand alone install, since I could not connect to wifi.

After install I still could not get the WiFi to sense a router to install updates.

While running the "non-connecting" re-booted fresh install on the PC and then later plugging in the USB installation thumbdrive (and its associated drivers), I opened the Driver Manager and found that it recognized the installed wifi device driver, but the driver was unchecked. Clicked for the system to use this driver... took awhile to make the changes, but had no problems after that connecting to wifi.

Cheers to LM users.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to linux. What is the device manager you used? Was it software with a GUI or was it run from the terminal?

Comment: Click on the linuxmint start menu (bottom left) type driver, and you will see the Driver Manager listed in the suite of GUI applications. OR you may be able to get to it using CLI by entering driver-manager

Comment: Unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work. See **Edit 2** in the OP.

Comment: If it is a laptop, sometimes there is a slide-switch on the side or front of laptop. Maybe there is a fn-key combination to turn wifi on.

Comment: I am using a computer with a USB adapter so there is no slider, unfortunately.

Comment: Read the last 3-sentences of this note first. If it is a laptop, sometimes there is a Wi-Fi slide-switch on the side or front of laptop. Maybe there is a fn-key combination to turn wifi on. Alternately, right click on the internet connectivity icon in the panel (bottom info row) on the right (hovering over the icon shows Network). You may have to check mark the Enable Wi-Fi option. Also this is where you select the Wi-Fi to connect to.

Comment: I don't have the option to enable wifi.

Comment: I hope this helped. I'm sorry but otherwise I am out of ideas and I have to go. Best wishes.

Comment: In the linuxmint forum I wrote an article about changing a wifi time-out setting. Search for comments by the user antioch. You might try a reboot then go back into the Network settings. My daughter's PC wifi radio died (they're just radios). Found an Amazon replacement for$6. Put it in and sprang to life. I hope this helped. I'm sorry but otherwise I am out of ideas and I have to go. Best wishes. I'll check back this evening.

Comment: Okay no worries thanks for the help.